# Fullscreen, resizable canvas in Elm not visible on page load

Tags: html5-canvas, elm

I'm using Elm 0.19 and the [joakin/elm-canvas](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/joakin/elm-canvas/4.0.1/) package.

All I'm trying to do is draw a canvas that spans the entire width and height of the screen and resizes dynamically as the window size changes. I've spent several hours debugging and researching but I'm just stuck.  I've tried multiple implementations, and I can get it to work, but not on initial page load.  Instead, it renders only after the update function gets called.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious, as I'm still very new to Elm.

Here's a link to the working Ellie code/demo showing the problem: https://ellie-app.com/6JZDxnQWPLSa1
Notice how the screen is blank until after a keypress event fires the update, and then the canvas appears.

Edit: adding code from the Ellie demo.

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Browser
import Browser.Dom exposing (Viewport, getViewport)
import Browser.Events exposing (onKeyDown, onResize)
import Canvas exposing (..)
import Canvas.Settings exposing (..)
import Canvas.Settings.Advanced exposing (..)
import Color
import Html exposing (Html, div)
import Html.Attributes exposing (style)
import Json.Decode as Decode
import Task


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        , update = update
        }


-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { screen : { width : Int, height : Int }
    }


init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init _ =
    ( { screen = { width = 800, height = 600 }
      }
    , Task.perform (\{ viewport } -> ScreenSize (round viewport.width) (round viewport.height)) getViewport
    )


-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = TurnLeft
    | TurnRight
    | MoveForward
    | Other
    | ScreenSize Int Int


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        TurnLeft ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        TurnRight ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        MoveForward ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        ScreenSize w h ->
            ( { model | screen = { width = w, height = h } }
            , Cmd.none
            )

        Other ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )


-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch
        [ onKeyDown keyDecoder
        , onResize ScreenSize
        ]


keyDecoder : Decode.Decoder Msg
keyDecoder =
    Decode.map toDirection (Decode.field "key" Decode.string)


toDirection : String -> Msg
toDirection string =
    case string of
        "ArrowLeft" ->
            TurnLeft

        "ArrowRight" ->
            TurnRight

        "ArrowUp" ->
            MoveForward

        _ ->
            Other


-- VIEW


clearScreen : Float -> Float -> Renderable
clearScreen width height =
    shapes [ fill Color.black ] [ rect ( 0, 0 ) width height ]


view : Model -> Html Msg
view { screen } =
    div
        [ style "display" "flex"
        , style "justify-content" "center"
        , style "align-items" "center"
        ]
        [ Canvas.toHtml
            ( screen.width, screen.height )
            []
            [ clearScreen (toFloat screen.width) (toFloat screen.height)
              , shapes [ fill Color.red ] [ rect ( 30, 30 ) 200 200 ]
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: Good point. I've attached the code from the Ellie demo I linked.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting problem though. I looks like a bug in joakin/elm-canvas. I would suggest making `screen` a `Maybe` instead of using arbitrary values initially. That solves the issue initially, but it'll clear the screen again when you resize. It might work to forcefully rerender it entirely when the screen resizes, but that's going to add a bit of mess. I'd suggest opening an issue on the github repo instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working example: https://ellie-app.com/6KrhJjGLwc5a1. It's blinking a bit, but the canvas is adjusted on resize. [This post](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/when-does-elm-not-update-the-ui/901/3) helped me a lot to find this workaround.

I added a `busy` prop to the model:

```
type alias Model =
    { screen : { width : Int, height : Int }
    , busy : Bool
    }
```

and I added a `PostScreenSize` to force the view to reload after `ScreenSize` done:

```
ScreenSize w h ->
    ( { model | screen = { width = w, height = h }, busy = True }
    , delay PostScreenSize
    )

PostScreenSize ->
    ( { model | busy = False }
    , Cmd.none
    )
```

Comment: Definitely a good workaround to the issue. I've already submitted the issue on GitHub because as @glennsl said, it seems to be a problem with the package.

Comment: For me, it's more a synchronization problem rather than a package issue. See, with some delay, the frame shows well. For those who are interested, [here the link to the thread](https://github.com/joakin/elm-canvas/issues/10) on GitHub.